# Get click URL from smartphone (Galaxy running Android)

Tags: android, galaxy

I have a smartphone (Galaxy S2 running Android 2.3.6) and I am interested in seeing the URLs I am clicking when I touch the screen while using certain apps.

For example, if I am playing a game app and it shows an ad, I want to know what URL I am clicking on for that ad when I touch the screen.

I am open to any solution (adding an app to the phone, simulating the smartphone on my local computer and looking through the html there...).  Thanks.

Comment: I have never heard that before. I don't think there is a way to figure it out. I think you cannot see the URL without clicking the ad.

Comment: What about simulating the mobile device app on a regular browser- I have seen program that allow you to simulate mobile apps, but it appears they are for apps you are developing yourself, not downloaded apps